# Insertion in innodb and update in myisam in Mysql database getting too slow

Tags: mysql, configuration, database-performance, database-connection, database-concurrency

I have recently done following changes in my sql server configurations

thread_cache_size=100

key_buffer_size=1G

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G

innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64

But after that insertion in Innodb table and update in mysiam table taking too long.
Any idea what's wrong

Comment: Locked tables that cause the insert and updates to be delayed?  When you update the myisam table, is the `WHERE` clause using an index?

Comment: yes. It is using index.I know about locking but What my question is regards to above settings which i thought will improve the performance. But after applying above setting performance is more degraded

Comment: Can you post any IO statistics and memory usage information?  Is the server running low on RAM and swapping?  If you connect to MySQL console and issue an insert query to one of these tables, what is the result (time)?  If you were already low on RAM, this could have made things worse by using more memory when you need to be reducing it in other areas.

Comment: Doesn't have the IO statistics and memory usage information. Let me check any tool from which i can find anything

Comment: On linux, `iotop` and `iostat` can show disk IO, and just use `top` or `free` to see basic CPU and memory usage.

Comment: If you don't have at least 8GB of RAM, you have set some things too high.  How much RAM do you have?  Let's see the queries.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Changing innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 help me in speeding the insertion